# SpriteKit Sound causes crash

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, skaction

So I implemented a sound file while a swipe gesture is made, and it always crashes when it should play the sound. There is no Debug Output. Since I am using the Yosemite Beta, I thought it is because of Xcode, showing me only the Thread 6 1.2 Breakpoint. So I downloaded the Xcode 6 Beta, and the Beta is showing me the Thread 1 1.1 Breakpoint.

My Code:

```
- (void)handleSwipeUp:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
if(PlayerBlockContact){
[Human.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 65)];
    NoSlide = true;

[self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"JumpSound.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO]];

[self performSelector:@selector(MenschAnimation) withObject:nil ];

NSLog(@"Jump");
}

}
```

Comment: Check if your sound file name is exactly spelled as in your command or the issue is your "MenschAnimation" selector is not valid. Comment out one to see where the issue is.

Comment: The filename is correct, and the MenschAnimation is valid. If I take the playSoundFIleNamed Action out, everything works fine.

Comment: Then your issue has to do with the sound. If you already checked the exact filename spelling, I suggest you change the sound file format to WAV and try again or try another sound file for testing purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A breakpoint is not a crash. I imagine you've added an exception breakpoint. If so, make sure it only breaks on Objective-C exceptions.

It's rather common for the underlying (C++) AVAudioPlayer and OpenAL to throw all kinds of exceptions, halting program execution if the exception breakpoint also catches C++ exceptions.